# Why won't this prophet Python module import? I have tried everything possible

Tags: python, installation, module, prophet

I am running Python version 3.7 and trying to create a stock prediction Python program using fbprophet. However, it doesn't want to install.

I have tried importing it using pip, through python, and using conda install. Nothing seems to work. Can I get some help here?

[Showing that it isn't importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqH7n.jpg)

Comment: Screenshots are not really welcome here and this one does not seem to convey much.

Answer (score 1):

Try with virtuanenv in python.

```
❯ python -m venv .venv
❯ source .venv/bin/activate
❯ pip install prophet
```

Then everything you installed will be in the virtual environment.

Here is the sample code.

> from prophet import Prophet
>
> print("imported successfully!")

And the output would be following:

```
❯ python sample.py
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
imported successfully!
```

Keep in mind that, every library you installed will be only in the virtual env and you have to source first, before running the code.

Comment: RuntimeError: CmdStan failed to install in repackaged directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for prophet
Failed to build prophet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Can you try installing `pip install cmdstanpy` first, then retrying install prophet?